# awk loop over range of records write to separate files

Tags: awk

I have a file with several thousand lines describing the output from an elastic wave mode
code. The size of the file is variable depending on the frequency, the thickness of the
model, and the number of modes found for the particular model. The header information
contains the number of modes found. The modes are numbered from 0 to N and are stored next
to the keyword MODE. Following are how the file looks for the first two modes. In this example there are a total of 4 modes, 0 through 4.
Following the record "I DEPTH Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4" are over a thousand records giving the amplitudes. I have shown only the first two records for the first two modes. It is very easy to pick off the individual MODE numbers using awk and the pattern /MODE /. I want to create individual files for each mode (mode_0, mode_1, ...) with the thousand or so values in each file corresponding to that mode. I can create the files with the first awk call, but am unable to get the thousand or so records of corresponding mode amplitude values into the files the first awk call creates. One unsuccessful attempt to do that is the second awk call.

```
    ########## MODE NUMBER is "  0"     (RAYLEIGH WAVE) ##########
I    DEPTH          Y1             Y2             Y3             Y4
1   3.000000E-01   9.999983E-01   1.166993E+06  -1.280462E-02   0.000000E+00
2   6.000000E-01   9.999933E-01   2.351593E+06  -2.580244E-02   0.000000E+00
     This continues for a thousand or so records.
-1  0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00

    ########## MODE NUMBER is "  1"     (RAYLEIGH WAVE) ##########
I    DEPTH          Y1             Y2             Y3             Y4        1   3.000000E-01   9.999960E-01   1.183126E+06  -1.280343E-02   0.000000E+00
2   6.000000E-01   9.999840E-01   2.367720E+06  -2.562274E-02   0.000000E+00
         This continues for a thousand or so records.
-1  0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00
```

The last line for an individual model always ends with a -1 in the first field of the last
record. The number of records is variable, typically 1000 or more records. Then the next mode
starts with exactly the same format as the previous mode, starting with 1 in the first
field of the third record and ending with -1 in the first field of the last record of the mode.

What I have been trying to do is:

1. Create a separate file for each mode labelled mode_0, mode_1, mode_2, ..., mode_N for each of the individual modes.
2. Write the mode amplitude values to the corresponding mode_n file. These values are the floating point numbers below the "I DEPTH ... " labels.

I am quite inexperienced with awk as you can see from my latest attempt below. The example
has a total of 5 modes, mode_0 through mode_4. The first call to awk works as expected,
creating the individual mode files. The second awk call is one of my many unsuccessful
attempts to write the values to the individual mode files. I also tried the awk range
pattern / 1  /,/ -1  / which also did not work. I tried to get the second
awk call to work for just one mode, listed below, also unsuccessfully. I tried to figure out how to grab all the mode amplitude values between the record with "I" in the first field  of the first line, and "-1", the first field in the last record of the mode amplitude values. Although the mode amplitude floating point numbers can be negative, the " -1 " is strictly integer and surrounded by spaces, making it a good pattern to search on for the last record of each individual mode amplitude value.

```
gawk '/MODE / {

if($6 == "0\"" ) $6 = 0 # Remove double quotes from MODE 0" which only occurs for mode 0.
  arr[i] = substr( $6,1,length($6-1))
 {print $0 >> ("mode_"arr[i])}
}' inputfile
```

```
gawk '{ for (i = 1 ; i <= 4; i++)
 if ( ( arr[i] == 0 ) &&
    (  $1 == " I " && $1 != " -1 ") )
 print $0 >> ("mode_"arr[i])
}' inputfile
```

Comment: If you want help parsing a file that contains multiple modes then provide a sample input file that has multiple (i.e. 2 or 3) modes and the associated expected output so we can better understand your problem (what is between mode blocks in  the file is just as important as what's inside the blocks) and have something we can copy/paste to test with. ALlso, please format all of your sample input, expected output, and code as Code Blocks, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting.

Comment: I added a second mode from the input file. It is formatted identically to the first one, that is. The expected output is N individual files, one for each mode, and labelled by mode number. The contents of the individual files should be the mode amplitude as shown above, that is an integer followed 5 floating point numbers. There are about 1000 records for each mode and terminated by a final record with a "-1" in the first. field

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you're focusing on the wrong thing.  It's the "MODE NUMBER is" pattern that is the thing to search for and trigger changing the output filename.  Everything else is just printed to the current output file.

Here's how to do that in perl.

I'm not sure if you want that "MODE NUMBER is" line (or the field header line with DEPTH, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4) included in the output, so I've added statements you can uncomment if you want them to be excluded.

```perl
$ cat split-modes.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<<>>) {
  # extract mode number, handling optional quote and leading spaces
  if (/MODE NUMBER is "? *(\d+)/i) {
    open($FH, ">", "mode_$1") || die "Couldn't open output file 'mode_$1': $!\n";

    # uncomment next line to exclude the "MODE NUMBER is" line from the output
    #next;
  };
  # Uncomment next line to exclude the "DEPTH Y1..Y4" header line
  #next if (/^\s*I\s/);

  print $FH $_;
}
```

or as a slightly simplified "one-liner" to run from the command line or in a shell script etc:

```
perl -n -e '
  if (/MODE NUMBER is "? *(\d+)/i) {
    open($FH, ">", "mode_$1");
    next;
  };
  next if (/^\s*I\s*/);
  print $FH $_;' inputfile
```

And here's roughly the same algorithm in `gawk`.  The main difference is that it takes slightly more work to extract the mode number, and it's generally a good idea to explicitly close a file handle in awk once we don't need it any more (this is done implicitly by the perl `open()` statement) - this isn't strictly necessary when you're only going to have five output files, but it's a good habit to develop.  See gawk manual section [5.9 Closing Input and Output Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html)

```c
gawk '
/MODE NUMBER is/ {
  # extract number(s) with 1-or-more digits in MODE line into array "a"
  match($0,/[0-9]+/,a);
  close(out);

  # we are only interested in the first element of a
  out = "mode_" a[0];

  #next;
};

#/^[[:space:]]*I[[:space:]]/ { next };

{ print $0 > out }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
gawk '{
  if ($1 == "##########") {
    FS = "\"";
    $0 = $0;
    close(modefile);
    modefile = "mode_"int($2);
    FS = " "
  } else {
    if ($1 != "-1")
      print $0 >> modefile
  }
}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be all you need, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '/MODE/{close(out); out="mode_"(cnt++)} {print > out}' file
```

but with just 1 record provided as sample input and no expected output, it's an untested guess.

Given your updated sample input showing that it's blank-line separated records, it's a bit simpler to handle by just using awk's "paragraph mode" (still using any awk):

```
awk -v RS= '{out="mode_"(NR-1); print > out; close(out)}' file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
    ########## MODE NUMBER is "  0"     (RAYLEIGH WAVE) ##########
I    DEPTH          Y1             Y2             Y3             Y4
1   3.000000E-01   9.999983E-01   1.166993E+06  -1.280462E-02   0.000000E+00
2   6.000000E-01   9.999933E-01   2.351593E+06  -2.580244E-02   0.000000E+00
     This continues for a thousand or so records.
-1  0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00

    ########## MODE NUMBER is "  1"     (RAYLEIGH WAVE) ##########
I    DEPTH          Y1             Y2             Y3             Y4        1   3.000000E-01   9.999960E-01   1.183126E+06  -1.280343E-02   0.000000E+00
2   6.000000E-01   9.999840E-01   2.367720E+06  -2.562274E-02   0.000000E+00
         This continues for a thousand or so records.
-1  0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00
```

```
$ awk -v RS= '{out="mode_"(NR-1); print > out; close(out)}' file
```

```
$ head mode_*
==> mode_0 <==
    ########## MODE NUMBER is "  0"     (RAYLEIGH WAVE) ##########
I    DEPTH          Y1             Y2             Y3             Y4
1   3.000000E-01   9.999983E-01   1.166993E+06  -1.280462E-02   0.000000E+00
2   6.000000E-01   9.999933E-01   2.351593E+06  -2.580244E-02   0.000000E+00
     This continues for a thousand or so records.
-1  0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00

==> mode_1 <==
    ########## MODE NUMBER is "  1"     (RAYLEIGH WAVE) ##########
I    DEPTH          Y1             Y2             Y3             Y4        1   3.000000E-01   9.999960E-01   1.183126E+06  -1.280343E-02   0.000000E+00
2   6.000000E-01   9.999840E-01   2.367720E+06  -2.562274E-02   0.000000E+00
         This continues for a thousand or so records.
-1  0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00
```

Comment: awk '/MODE/{close(out); out="mode_"(cnt++)} {print > out}' file generates the following error: fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value  My first awk script correctly creates the individual mode_0, mode_1, ... files. What I am having the difficulty with is extracting the corresponding mode amplitude values in the 1000 or so records after the ########## MODE NUMBER is "  0"     (RAYLEIGH WAVE) ########## line

Comment: @Bob then it sounds your given example doesn't match with your actual data format and its first line doesn't contain `MODE` string in it.

Comment: You could work around that error by changing `{print > out}` to `out{print > out}` but if you're having that problem it means the input you're testing with doesn't look like the sample input in your question so you might run into other issues and there might be better ways of doing whatever it is you want to do with THAT input.

Comment: If the example you provided doesn't look like you're real input then we can't help you come up with the best way to parse your real input. If you run either script I posted against the sample input you posted it **will** do what you want. If the sample input you posted doesn't look like your real input then edit your question to fix your example and, again, please add the expected output to your question.

Comment: Regarding `What I am having the difficulty with is extracting the corresponding mode amplitude values` - to be clear, you do not need to do that as your mode values start at `0` and increase by 1 for each record so all you need is a counter, `cnt` in my first script and `NR` in my second.

Comment: I finally solved this. The script below gives me exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this. The following very simple script gives me exactly what I needed:

- The first pattern searches for the record that contains the mode number.
- The second range pattern exactly brackets the beginning and end of the amplitude values written to a file that contains the mode number in its name.
- The spaces in the patterns ensure the correct records are grabbed.

```
gawk '/MODE /{ if ($6 == "0\"" ) $6 = 0
    modenum = substr( $6,1,length($6-1)) 
    close(modefile)
    modefile = "mode_"modenum
}
/ I  /,/ -1  /{
    print $0 >> modefile
}' infile
```

Comment: It's hard to read as it's not formatted as a Code Block (see how you formatted code in  your question and do the same in answers) but it looks like there's some things in your awk script that don't make sense to do, e.g. you appear to be using a range expression and closing multiple files and closing one file multiple times and using an array for some unknown purpose with a single unset index.